# How can I write a recursion for this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

How can I write a recursion for this function?

```
def randomWord(args):
    yield random.choice(args)

list = ['book', 'apple', 'word']
books = randomWord(list)
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
```

After each `print(next(books))`  I need to get a random word from `list`

Comment: Why do you need recursion? Just use an infinite loop.

Comment: Just use `while True: yield random.choice(args)`

Comment: @Barmar It's important to use recursion

Comment: Why is it "important"? If it's a requirement of a homework assignment, say so.

Comment: What is the actual problem that this code tries to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 3.3 you can just use the `yield from` keyword.

```
def randomWord(args):
    yield random.choice(args)
    yield from randomWord(args)

list = ['book', 'apple', 'word']
books = randomWord(list)
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
print(next(books))
```

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that this will eventually hit recursion depth limits.

Comment: Yes, it eventually will. But that's how recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

```
def randomWord(args):
    yield random.choice(args)

list = ['book', 'apple', 'word']
books = randomWord(list)

def recurse(n):
    if n == 0: return # base case

    print(next(books))
    recurse(n-1)

recurse(99) # the recurse function will call itself 99 times (for a total of 100 calls)
```

Not sure why you would want this as opposed to a loop...